# Magento 2: Product Custom Tab with Attribute WYSWYG shows broken image

Tags: custom, magento2.2.2, product-tab

I am running Magento CE 2.2.2 and I need to create another TAB in the product information page near the details and review tabs.

I created a new Attribute, named it "Tab". In the attribute, options set the input type to Text Area and enabled WYSIWYG Editor.

When I put Text in the field, the text shows fine. When I insert an image, in backend shows fine, but in frontend, it shows broken.

When inspected the code noticed that the code is generated wrong.

the code shows like this:

```
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" rohs-weee.jpg"}}"="" width="800" height="233">
```

when it should show like this:

```
<img src="http://10.1.1.30/Magento2.2.2/pub/media/wysiwyg/RoHS-WEEE.jpg" width="800" height="233">
```

I am thinking that I missed some link to convert the link from the editor to the actual link. **Does anyone know how to fix this?**

This is a link to download the code of my block:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmi7pvkd206s7vd/Test_Tab.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if your question not solve.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you need to filter the WYSIWYG output to convert it to the proper markup using the FilterProvider.

Extend the template block class and inject the filter provider: `\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider`.

Add a new method to your class:

```
public function renderOutput($wysiwygCode) {
  return $this->filterProvider
    ->getBlockFilter()
    ->filter($wysiwygCode);
}
```

Then use the `renderOutput` method in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by this below code. Add this code in your phtml :

```
$content = '<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" rohs-weee.jpg"}}"="" width="800" height="233">';
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterManager = $om->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider')->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
echo $filterManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your description.phtml is shows the "Tab" field data,
then please use following code for appropriate data of "Tab" attribute.

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getTab(), 'tab') ?>
```